# Loading all images from folder & make named Images from them

Tags: java, image, object, loading

Title is a bit rambling but not sure the best way to describe it. Still a Java newb (Transitioning from Obj-C) so I know how to code but not sure if/how to apply this in java specifically.

Basically, I want to do this:

```
ImageIcon a0amora = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("resource/" + "a0amora.png"));
ImageIcon a1act1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("resource/" + "a1act1.png"));
ImageIcon a2hello = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("resource/" + "a2hello.png"));
ImageIcon a3anyonethere = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("resource/" + "a3anyonethere.png"));
ImageIcon a4imhere = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("resource/" + "a4imhere.png"));
ImageIcon a5stuck = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("resource/" + "a5stuck.png"));
ImageIcon a6silence = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("resource/" + "a6silence.png"));
ImageIcon a7ashamed = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("resource/" + "a7ashamed.png"));
ImageIcon a8free = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("resource/" + "a8free.png"));
ImageIcon a9endact = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("resource/" + "a9endact.png"));
```

But in a procedure that will read all PNGs in the folder and make a new ImageIcon named after the file name, so I don't have to assign each one manually.

Comment: This isn't possible. You can't generate new named variables programmatically. What you can do is store them in a map, so you could call `map.get("a0amora")`, and it would return the proper resource. Unfortunately, since these are resources inside the jar file, you'd have to mess around with a ZipInputStream to scan the jar for resources. Alternatively, you could add an additional file that lists all the resources, and use that to grab the icons.

Comment: @ChrisBode: You could use auto-generated source code.

Comment: If you are using copy-paste to write a part of code - it means you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd list the files in the target directory and add them all to a `Map` something like this...

```
File  directory = new File("resource");
Map<String, ImageIcon> iconMap = new HashMap<String, ImageIcon>();

for (File file : directory.listFiles())
{
    // could also use a FileNameFilter
    if(file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".png"))
    {
        iconMap.put(file.getName(), new ImageIcon(file.getPath()));
    }
}
```

Comment: The constructor `ImageIcon(File)` does not exist.

Comment: @JoshM Good catch.  I guess that's what I get for changing the codee in my answer without running it past a compiler.  Fixed the example to pass in the file name instead of the `File`

Comment: I think you are looking for `file.getPath()` as opposed to `file.getName()`

Comment: I ended up using this. It needed some modifications to run and work properly, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the 'real path' to that directory on the server.  Use it to establish a `File` object.
2. Create a [`FilenameFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) for PNG.
3. Use [`File.listFiles(FilenameFilter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) on that source directory.  That will return a `File[]` containing references to the PNG files.

That is assuming the images are on the class-path, as loose `File` resources.  If they are in a Jar, we must iterate the `ZipEntry` objects of the Jar to dynamically discover what it contains.

Comment: This will be handy. Either this or using a HashMap as Chris suggested.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Java 8, you could try something like this:

```
public List<ImageIcon> get(){
    final FileFilter filter = f -> f.getName().endsWith(".png");
    final File res = new File(getClass().getResource("resource").getPath());
    return Arrays.asList(res.listFiles(filter)).stream().map(f -> new ImageIcon(f.getPath())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If you aren't, it would not be that hard to modify the code, you get the general idea though.